# odoo.tools.convert.ParseError when restarting odoo-bin

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-15

I am working through the developer tutorial [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/10_actions.html).

I have added two `action` buttons to a tree view.

Everything worked fine until I restarted the server after adding the `button` tags to the XML `view`. I then received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/keith/src/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 1246, in preload_registries
    registry = Registry.new(dbname, update_module=update_module)
  File "/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 87, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 470, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 363, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 222, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
  File "/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 69, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
  File "/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 745, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 811, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 731, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 691, in _tag_root
    raise ParseError(msg) from None  # Restart with "--log-handler odoo.tools.convert:DEBUG" for complete traceback
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /custom/estate/views/estate_property_offer_views.xml:3
Invalid view estate.property.offer.tree (estate.estate_property_offer_view_tree) definition in estate/views/estate_property_offer_views.xml

View error context:
'-no context-'
```

If I remove the button tags, the server starts without error
(`./odoo-bin --addons-path=../custom,addons -d rd-demo -u estate --dev xml`).

I can then add the buttons back and they work correctly but as soon as I restart the server, I get the error again.

Here is the complete record from the `view`:

```
    <record id="estate_property_offer_view_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">estate.property.offer.tree</field>
        <field name="model">estate.property.offer</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Offers">
                <field name="price"/>
                <field name="partner_id"/>
                <field name="validity"/>
                <field name="date_deadline"/>
                <field name="state"/>
                
                <button name="action_accept" type="object" icon="fa-check" style="color:green" states="new"/>
                <button name="action_refuse" type="object" icon="fa-close" style="color:red" states="new"/>
                
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: First thing i miss are `string` (labels) on the buttons. Did you try to add them?

Comment: Yes I originally had `string` parameters but removed them because I only want to show the icons. The error still occurs with `string` parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view validation will fail when it calls the [relaxng](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/tools/view_validation.py#L159) method and will raise the following error:

```
ERROR:RELAXNGV:RELAXNG_ERR_INVALIDATTR: Invalid attribute style for element button
```

It is called to validate the following [views](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/tools/view_validation.py#L172): `calendar`, `graph`, `pivot`, `search`, `tree`, `activity`. You can check the ([common.rng](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/addons/base/rng/common.rng#L336)) file in the base module, no `style` attribute in the button definition.

To fix that error, you must remove the `style` attribute

Answer (score 3):

Remove the style from the button on `tree` **view**

```
<button name="action_refuse" type="object" icon="fa-close"  states="new"/>
```

**style** attribute is not adapting in **tree** `architecture` for `button` only, you can do with **class-based**.

**With CLass**:

```
    <button name="action_refuse" type="object" icon="fa-close"  states="new" class="btn-primary my_class"/> <!--my_class your custom class  -->
```